# How to pass a variable to search using Regular Expression.

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to pass a value to a function and inside function i'd like to use that value to search a line from a text file using Regular expression.

But getting the error:

Code:

```
import re

def search(Key_Word):
   f= open("LICENSE.txt","r")
   for i in range(0,10000):
       d= f.readlines()
       match=re.search(r"Key_word",d)
       if match:
           print d

Key_Word="TERMS AND CONDITIONS FOR ACCESSING OR OTHERWISE USING PYTHON"
search(Key_Word)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\rough.py", line 12, in <module>
    search(Key_Word)
  File "C:\Python27\rough.py", line 7, in search
    match=re.search(r"Key_word",d)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

please help..

Answer (score 0):

`f.readlines()` returns a list of lines, you probably need to use `f.readline()` to read one line.